# <input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /> should not text-transform on the "UI" but send upperCase value to server

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" type="text" id="roleName" name="roleName" class="form-control width200px" [(ngModel)]="role.roleName">
```

The UI is affected and upper casing the input, I just want to send the role.roleName to server in upper case without transforming it on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

NgModel is two-way binding, therefore if the value transformed, then the UI will be reflected as well. If you would like to have different value, you may try to split the value into two parameters, one to view and another use to send to the server.

Sample:

```
<input oninput="role.roleName = this.value.toUpperCase()" type="text" id="roleName" name="roleName" class="form-control width200px" [(ngModel)]="role.somethingElse">
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to make it uppercase before you put the value into the request object.

In Typescript simply use .toUpperCase()

Or, you can also use the extended format of ngmodel with a setter on your model.

.ts

```
 class Role {
      roleName: string;
    
      getName(): string {
        return this.roleName;
      }
      setName(value: string): void {
        this.roleName = value.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
```

.html

```
<input
    type="text"
    id="roleName"
    name="roleName"
    class="form-control width200px"
    [ngModel]="role.getName()"
    (ngModelChange)="role.setName($event)"
  />
```

Please check on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3u48kn